# Sum Jtable coumn values in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, textfield

guys, my question is about jtable column values, I am stuck on a problem. I want to sum jtable column values and put it into the text field. I am inserting values into jtable and if a row is empty, it is not calculating the total afterward. I couldn't understand what is the problem. I created a method and call it on button event.

```
public void getSum(){

    int total=0;
    for(int i=0; i<JV_tbl.getRowCount(); i++){
        int amount = Integer.parseInt((String) JV_tbl.getValueAt(i, 6));

        total+=amount;
    }
    JV_totalDebit_box.setText(String.valueOf(total));

}
```

and the button event code.

```
private void btn_entrySaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent             evt) {                                              
     model = (DefaultTableModel)JV_tbl.getModel();
     model.addRow(new Object[]{
         jv_no_box.getText(),
         JV_entry_box.getText(),
         ((JTextField)date_txt.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText(),
         JV_Acc_code.getText(),
         JV_acc_title.getText(),
         JV_desc_box.getText(),
         JV_debit_box.getText(),
         JV_credit_box.getText(),
         prep_box.getText(),
         checked_box.getText(),
         approved_box.getText()

     });

     getSum();

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Look at the error stack trace you have in your console. What does the javadoc of Integer.parseInt() says when the given string to parse doesn't represent a valid integer? And besides, why do you store Strings in this column if it's supposed to contain integers?

Comment: it is not showing any error in the stack trace.

Comment: Some related [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjtable%5d%20sum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your getSum() function as below. It will remove all the blank rows and will continue the total afterward.

```
public void getSum(){
    int rowcount1 = JV_tbl.getRowCount();
    DefaultTableModel tbm1 = (DefaultTableModel) JV_tbl.getModel();
    for(int i = rowcount1-1; i >=0; i--){
        if(JV_tbl.getValueAt(i, 6) == null){
            tbm1.removeRow(i);
        }       
    }

    int total=0;
    for(int i=0; i<JV_tbl.getRowCount(); i++){
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(JV_tbl.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());

        total+=amount;
    }
    JV_totalDebit_box.setText(String.valueOf(total));

}
```